# .NET Tab Control Not Scrolling

Tags: .net, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a regular old tab control sitting on a form.  I have a user control dropped inside of the tab pages and it is definitely larger than the viewable area of the tab page.  For some reason, though, the tab page will not show scrollbars even with AutoScroll set to true.  Does anyone know a way around this?  I'm pretty sure I'm thinking about that correctly.  The tab page should scroll, right?

Comment: Sorry about that.... Winforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:** Well, I didn't have autoscroll set to true on the user control. I was assuming that the tab page would catch that the control it contained was too big but, I guess that's not the case.